# Why is the identity relation not axiomatizable?

Tags: first-order-logic

I have heard of the result but never have seen the formal proof that rhe identity relation cannot be defined by a finite sets of axioms in first order logic. Does anyone knows the proof or where i can look for it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you meaning that [first-order equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) include the schema for substitution ?

Comment: More or less, it's a proof that in first order logic we can't characterize the identity relation with a finite set of axioms, which implies that the identity relation is a primitive notion.